# Open URL with custom BROWSER

Tags: android

Good day!

Guys, I have a problem and want your help.

Through a WebView, how do I get when clicked by the user, do not open the options of standard browsers (eg chrome and internet). I saw an app by clicking the link to the page opens normally however, as if open in a custom browser. I found it very interesting, and I wonder how this mechanics.

If anyone know how to create an app that perform the same procedure I am grateful.

For better doubt the APP is this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tachanfil.jornaisdobrasil&hl=pt-BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up `WebViewClient` like

```
this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return true;
    }
});
```

Then your app will display all links in your `WebView` instead of opening browser

Comment: Amazing, soo fast asnwer! I will try update my code and post results for any future questions =]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing setting your client as the webview client - Refer to

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29

Comment: I now have a place to research and take my doubts
! thanks